# C - test string equivalence without strcmp

Tags: c, string, equivalent

in one of my university assignments I am restricted in the libraries I use. I am new to C and pointers and want to see if two strings (or should I say char's) are equal.

Part of me wants to loop through every char of the 'char string' and test equivalence, but then it comes back how to test equivalence (lol).

Any help is appreciated.

edit: I am seeing this:

```
  warning: result of comparison against a string literal is
  unspecified (use strncmp instead) [-Wstring-compare]
```

which leads to a segmentation fault. I know it has to do with this piece of code because all I added was:

```
    if (example.name == "testName"){
        printf("here!\n");
    }
```

Comment: `char`s are just small integers, so you can compare them like you would any other integers.

Comment: Should of made an edit of what I'm getting. OP is updated

Comment: In 'example.name == "testName"' you are not comparing strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Part of me wants to loop through every char of the 'char string' and test equivalence

That's exactly what you need to do. Make a function `mystrcmp` with the signature identical to [regular `strcmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html),

```
int mystrcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

and write your own implementation.

> but then it comes back how to test equivalence.

When you loop character-by-character, you test equivalence of individual characters, not strings. Characters in C can be treated like numbers: you can compare them for equality using `==`, check what character code is less than or greater than using `<` and `>`, and so on.

The only thing left to do now is deciding when to stop. You do that by comparing the current character of each string to zero, which is the null terminator.

Don't forget to forward-declare your `mystrcmp` function before using it.

Answer (score 2):

A string in C is terminated with null character`(0x00 or \0)`.You should compare both strings in a loop character by character till null char for either of the string is reached.

Loop should be broken if characters are not equal.

EDIT:

To answer your edit in question:

You should take two character pointers pointing to both strings and then copmare them like

```
//loop start,loop till null for any one of the string is found

if(*ptr1 != *ptr2)
{
   //break loop
} 

ptr1++;ptr2++;

//end loop

if((*ptr1 == *ptr2) &&(*ptr1== 0x00))


{
      //strings are equal
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Given that this is a university assignment, you should pay heed to chars just being small integers. You should also pay heed that C strings are contiguous memory buffers terminated by a binary zero (0x00).

You should also learn about pointer math. You will learn ways to shorten the code you have to write while learning something really interesting concerning the C language and how computers work. It will certainly help you if you choose a career on lower-level programming.